# How can I get results without HTML codes with preg_match_all in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am using this code. But it is returning with html codes.

```
$site=file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/".$link);
preg_match_all('/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/',$site,$baslik);
```

It is returning like < h1>result< /h1>. But I want just see the result. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you `var_dump($baslik)` to see `result` in `$baslik[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

using DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/' . $link);

$h1Nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1');

foreach ($h1Nodes as $h1Node) {
    echo "\n" . $h1Node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: How can I do that with regex?

Comment: @FiratCihangir: don't use regex, use this way.

Comment: @FiratCihangir what do you mean how can i do that with regex? this is by way of HTML Parsers which is the proper way of parsing html markup